# How to close python asyncio transport?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, transport

I'm working on a project which uses python asyncio socket server. The problem is that the implementation of the server doesn't call .close() on the transport when the server stops. This seems to leave clients connected and causes crashes in other parts of the code.

Python documents say that transports need to be closed explicitly, but in this project I don't know where I can close them because there is no reference to the transports that are created for each client.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-dev.html#close-transports-and-event-loops

Here is the code:

```
"""
Socket server forwarding request to internal server
"""
import logging
try:
    # we prefer to use bundles asyncio version, otherwise fallback to trollius
    import asyncio
except ImportError:
    import trollius as asyncio


from opcua import ua
from opcua.server.uaprocessor import UaProcessor

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class BinaryServer(object):

    def __init__(self, internal_server, hostname, port):
        self.logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
        self.hostname = hostname
        self.port = port
        self.iserver = internal_server
        self.loop = internal_server.loop
        self._server = None
        self._policies = []

    def set_policies(self, policies):
        self._policies = policies

    def start(self):

        class OPCUAProtocol(asyncio.Protocol):

            """
            instanciated for every connection
            defined as internal class since it needs access
            to the internal server object
            FIXME: find another solution
            """

            iserver = self.iserver
            loop = self.loop
            logger = self.logger
            policies = self._policies

            def connection_made(self, transport):
                self.peername = transport.get_extra_info('peername')
                self.logger.info('New connection from %s', self.peername)
                self.transport = transport
                self.processor = UaProcessor(self.iserver, self.transport)
                self.processor.set_policies(self.policies)
                self.data = b""

            def connection_lost(self, ex):
                self.logger.info('Lost connection from %s, %s', self.peername, ex)
                self.transport.close()
                self.processor.close()

            def data_received(self, data):
                logger.debug("received %s bytes from socket", len(data))
                if self.data:
                    data = self.data + data
                    self.data = b""
                self._process_data(data)

            def _process_data(self, data):
                buf = ua.utils.Buffer(data)
                while True:
                    try:
                        backup_buf = buf.copy()
                        try:
                            hdr = ua.Header.from_string(buf)
                        except ua.utils.NotEnoughData:
                            logger.info("We did not receive enough data from client, waiting for more")
                            self.data = backup_buf.read(len(backup_buf))
                            return
                        if len(buf) < hdr.body_size:
                            logger.info("We did not receive enough data from client, waiting for more")
                            self.data = backup_buf.read(len(backup_buf))
                            return
                        ret = self.processor.process(hdr, buf)
                        if not ret:
                            logger.info("processor returned False, we close connection from %s", self.peername)
                            self.transport.close()
                            return
                        if len(buf) == 0:
                            return
                    except Exception:
                        logger.exception("Exception raised while parsing message from client, closing")
                        self.transport.close()
                        break

        coro = self.loop.create_server(OPCUAProtocol, self.hostname, self.port)
        self._server = self.loop.run_coro_and_wait(coro)
        print('Listening on {}:{}'.format(self.hostname, self.port))

    def stop(self):
        self.logger.info("Closing asyncio socket server")
        self.loop.call_soon(self._server.close)
        self.loop.run_coro_and_wait(self._server.wait_closed())
```

As you can see when we call stop() on this server class the asyncio server calls it's close method. However if clients are connected the created transports never get closed.

The project repository is here https://github.com/FreeOpcUa/python-opcua/ , you can take a look at Issue 137.

What is the correct way to close the transport object?

Comment: You may keep a list of active transports in `BinaryServer` attribute, e.g. by `self.iserver.transports.append(transport)` in `connection_made()`

Comment: I tried this and it can work. However, how can I close the correct transport in `connection_lost()` ? Otherwise clients connecting and disconnecting over time could make my `self.iserver.transporst` list very large.

Comment: I think I figured out that I can simply do `self.iserver.transports.remove(self.transport)` in `connection_lost()` to remove transports from the list as clients disconnect. If this doesn't work I suppose I can loop through the list and check for `transport.is_closing` and remove that one from the list. Thanks for the help I will post the answer after testing.

Comment: Yes, `self.iserver.transports.remove(self.transport)` should work fine.

As a side note please keep in mind that the actual connection closing will be performed on the next event loop iteration after `transport.close()` call.

In practice it's important in tests mostly: test should push something like `await asyncio.sleep(0)` after transports closing.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this by applying this approach:

#self.OPCUAServer - this is my opcua server

nodes = []

nodes.append(self.OPCUAServer.get_node("ns=0; s=Measurements")) #Adding two root nodes
nodes.append(self.OPCUAServer.get_node("ns=1; s=Calibrations")) #to the list
self.OPCUAServer.delete_nodes(nodes, True) # Recursively call delete_nodes with this list
self.OPCUAServer.stop()